# Split Characters in a cell to individual columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a dataset where a column contains 1 and 0 in a single cell which reference security authorities in a software program.  I need to split these out into individual columns as these denote (0) No Access and (1) Access

Example:

```
Column1
01001
```

Expected Outcome

```
Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 Column5
0       1       0       0       1
```

Appreciate any help on this sql statement to make this happen

Thanks
Paul

Comment: Column1 data type?

Comment: Is this a string? A bitfield?

Comment: Will the value of `Column1` always be 5 digits, or could it be more? *How many* more?

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the assumptions proposed by @Stu, a simplified version would be

```
declare @v varchar(5) = '01001'

select 
  substring(@v,1,1) as column1,
  substring(@v,2,1)  as column2,
  substring(@v,3,1)  as column3,
  substring(@v,4,1)  as column4,
  substring(@v,5,1) as column5
```

Comment: Sometimes it's too easy to overlook the obvious ;-)

Comment: @James this is exactly what i required and yes I did overlook this.  I implemented this statement and it has worked and I was able to get the result that I was after to complete my report and push into production.

Answer (score 1):

Making an *assumption* that you would have clarified if the length were variable (which would be cruicial information to include) and that the value is always 5 *characters* as indicated in the question title.

You can use a set of *conditional case expressions* to pivot the data after it's split into rows using `substring`

```
with n as (select n from (values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5))v(n))
select 
    max(case when n=1 then c end) as column1,
    max(case when n=2 then c end) as column2,
    max(case when n=3 then c end) as column3,
    max(case when n=4 then c end) as column4,
    max(case when n=5 then c end) as column5
from t
cross join n
cross apply (values (Substring(col1,n,1)))v(c)
```

[Demo DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6eb869aeb575691b2e4a6d4ec2914f2d)